# 3 Table Join giving me duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a 3 table join and it's giving me duplicate records so I'm unsure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
SELECT e.*, cs.*, c.* FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN coffee_shop cs ON e.shop_id = cs.shop_id 
LEFT JOIN coffee c ON cs.shop_id = c.shop_id
```

[image]

I want the `coffee_shop` table to join on the `employee` table's shop_id and the `coffee` table to join on `coffee_shop's` shop_id to perform a 3 table join. However it's giving me duplicate rows (9 rows) when all the tables only have 3 rows each.

[image]

How do I perform this join without duplicates?

**Edit:**

If I do only the join on the first two tables(employee and coffee_shop) it is as expected

[image]

I want to perform one more join from `coffee` onto `coffee_shop`. Which should also return 3 rows

**Here is the result I want:**

[image]

Comment: Why only 4 columns have values?

Comment: because you have 1 to many relationships , you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: As @eshirvana alluded to, your `coffee` table has 3 records for `shop_id` = 16. Since the three rows from your `employee` and `coffee_shop` join all have `shop_id` = 16, you will end up with 9 rows after joining onto `coffee`. Essentially, you will have to specify which row from `coffee` you would like to join for `shop_id` = 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you 3 rows for your use-case. For each `shop_id` in the `coffee` table, this will return the row with the first `coffee_id`.

Depending on which coffee you want to return, you can adjust the logic for the `row_rank` field.

```
SELECT e.*, cs.*, c.* 
FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN coffee_shop cs ON e.shop_id = cs.shop_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY shop_id ORDER BY coffee_id) as row_rank
    FROM coffee
) c ON cs.shop_id = c.shop_id and c.row_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DISTINCT` in your query like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT  e.*, cs.*, c.* FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN coffee_shop cs ON e.shop_id = cs.shop_id 
LEFT JOIN coffee c ON cs.shop_id = c.shop_id
```

Comment: I tried and it's still giving me duplicate rows

Comment: `DISTINCT` cannot return duplicate records. All of them must have something different. Try to remove that different attribute and try again.

Answer (score 0):

if your main tables is employee,

```
SELECT e.*, cs.*, c.* FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN coffee_shop cs ON e.shop_id = cs.shop_id 
LEFT JOIN coffee c ON cs.shop_id = c.shop_id
```

Comment: also gives me duplicate rows (9 of them) when expecting 3

Comment: i think that is no relation between employee and coffe
1. are you trying to get employee data and his coffe_shop? or
2. to get data coffe_shop and what are they sold ( coffe)
3. to get data selling